# How to Pass Input Value into Cypher Query?

Tags: javascript, forms, neo4j, cypher, ejs

I'm running nodejs and from an ejs page, I'm trying to send an input value into a Cypher query that will result in a vis.js display of a graph.
**Note**: All javascript actions are taking place on the ejs page, there is no server contact in this case.

I can render the Neo4j graph no problem when running the query **without** any attempts of adding the input value.

**This Works** Clicking this button...

```
    <input type="submit" onclick="displayGraph()" value='Display Graph' class="button">
```

...runs this function which includes the Cypher query (no input in this query) and renders the Neo4j graph as expected.

```
    function displayGraph() {
        // Create the authorization header for the ajax request.
        AUTHORIZATION = "Basic " + btoa("abc"+":"+"123");

        // Post Cypher query to return node and relations and return results as graph.
        restPost({
            "statements": [
                {
                    "statement": `MATCH (bry:Brewery)-[r:BREWS]->(b:Beer {name: 'Pliny the Elder'})-[r2:IS_A]->(bt:BeerType)
                                    Optional Match (b)-[r3:BREWED_WITH]->(h:Hop) 
                                    Return bry,r,b,r2,bt,r3,h`,
                    "resultDataContents": ["graph"]
                }
            ]
        }).done(function (data) {
            
            // Parse results and convert it to vis.js compatible data.
            var graphData = parseGraphResultData(data);
            var nodes = convertNodes(graphData.nodes);
            var edges = convertEdges(graphData.edges);
            var visData = {
                nodes: nodes,
                edges: edges
            };
            displayVisJsData(visData);
        });
    }
```

**This Doesn't Work** If I use an input field to capture the name of a beer...

```
<label>
    Beer Name:<input name="inputbeer" id="inputbeer" type="text">
</label>
```

...and then click the same button...

```
<input type="submit" onclick="displayGraph()" value='Display Graph' class="button">
```

...I run the similar function, but have tried a number of variations on passing the input value into the Cypher query like this (everything is the same as the function seen above, just amending the Cypher query)...

```
MATCH (bry:Brewery)-[r:BREWS]->(b:Beer {name: '$inputbeer'})-[r2:IS_A]->(bt:BeerType)
                                    Optional Match (b)-[r3:BREWED_WITH]->(h:Hop) 
                                    Return bry,r,b,r2,bt,r3,h
```

...this and other variations don't work. I've tried {name: {inputbeer}}... {name: {$inputbeer}}... {name: $inputbeer}... so many possibilities.
I'm guessing it's a simple format issue, but I'm at a loss.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You should *really* have some form of abstraction, or information hiding, over your database. I mean, what is the point of exposing your database directly, anyway? You're better of if your users have proper access, and can use the official tools. This is bad, bad idea, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use [Javascript template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The syntax you are looking for is

```
const injectedString = 'containing a variable';
const templateString = `This is a string ${injectedString}`;
console.log(templateString);
//logs "This is a string containing a variable";
```

**HOWEVER,**

### DO NOT DO IT THAT WAY

This leaves you open to injection attacks, e.g. a input value of `'aBeerName'}) DETACH DELETE bry //` for `inputthebeer` would delete several nodes

## Use parameters

### If you're using the REST API

Use `params` to pass the parameters and let Neo4j safely escape and inject them into the query.

```
{
  "query" : "MATCH (bry:Brewery)-[r:BREWS]->(b:Beer {name: {inputthebeer}})-[r2:IS_A]->(bt:BeerType) Return bry,r,b,r2,bt,r3,h",
  "params" : {
    "inputthebeer" : "aBeerName",
  }
}
```

It's not clear how your `restPost()` works, but consult the [REST API documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-use-parameters) for examples.
The important part is that your query string should contain `{name: {inputthebeer}}` and that you should add `inputthebeer` as a parameter.

### Using the Javascript driver

A better solution is probably to use the [Neo4j Javascript Driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver).

Install it with `npm`

```
npm install neo4j-driver
```

or if you're not using npm or bundling your source, include it in your HTML

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/neo4j-driver@X.Y.Z/lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js"></script>
```

You'll need to initialize the driver and open a session, then

```
session
  .run(
    'MATCH (bry:Brewery)-[r:BREWS]->(b:Beer {name: $inputthebeer})-[r2:IS_A]->bt:BeerType) Return bry,r,b,r2,bt,r3,h',
    {
      inputthebeer: 'aBeerName'
    }
  )
```

The important thing to note in this example is that this is **NOT** a Javascript template literal. The value `$inputthebeer` is literally in the string, and the *driver* is passing the parameter, and Neo4j safely escapes the variable (preventing injection attacks)

## WARNING

It looks like the Neo4j REST API may be exposed publicly - if this is the case, the injection attack above may be moot, as attackers could directly execute any query by sending requests directly to the REST API

Answer (score -1):

After a little more experimenting, I am able to pass the input value to my Cypher query.

2 modifications were necessary:

1. I needed to add a var inside my function that would capture the value of the input:

```
var inputthebeer = document.getElementById("inputbeer").value;
```

2. I had to update my Cypher query to allow me to insert that var:

```js
`
MATCH (bry:Brewery)-[r:BREWS]->(b:Beer {name: '`+inputthebeer+`'})-[r2:IS_A]->(bt:BeerType) 
Optional Match (b)-[r3:BREWED_WITH]->(h:Hop) 
Return bry,r,b,r2,bt,r3,h
`
```

Comment: This leaves you open to an injection attack.

Comment: Thanks @Codebling, I've changed my input from the field input to a dropdown select... `<select class="form-control" type="text" name="inputbeer" id="inputbeer">
        <% beer.forEach(function(beer){ %>
            <option><%= beer.name %></option>
        <% }) %>
    </select>`
...but understand that the answer you share above is the best way to go about it. So I'll leave my piece here as a 'cautionary tale' for others.

Comment: I thought about this a bit more -- I realized that if the REST endpoint is exposed to the world, anyone can execute arbitrary Cypher on your Neo4j server. Keep it in mind! Glad you found some solutions that work, though!